# Looking for a federated learning framework with hierarchical architecture support

Tags: open-source, framework

I'm looking for a federated learning framework which also supports hierarchical structures. All entities should be able to run on different machines/VMs. The architecture should look like the following graph:

[image]
I came across [Flwr](https://flower.dev/docs/index.html) which unfortunately did not support hierarchical structures as well as [FedLab](https://github.com/SMILELab-FL/FedLab/tree/master/examples/hierarchical-hybrid-mnist), which does not seem to have a stable build yet.